# How to access the original manager of a Django model?

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to use the original manager of a model `A`. But I find that some teammate has changed `objects` to a custom manager, such as:

```
class A(models.Model):
    objects = SomeManager()
    ...
```

In this case, how can I get the original manager without changing the code of the model?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that it isn't replaced as well, you can use the [base manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#base-managers):

```
A._base_manager.all()
```